# Could you please help me simplifying the highlighted parts , just simplifying and paraphrasing Not defining, please

Tags: word-meaning

> It's Ivy week for the **Upper East Side** teens of **Constance Billiard and St**. **Jude's** and the **visiting representatives' arrival** **brings more than just college applications** . **Cut-throat rivalry** is at its sharpest this week as the students compete for prestigious positions. Blair discovers a shocking but juicy secret about Serena and plots to drop the bomb at the best possible moment. Dan is sure that landing the **coveted usher position** with the **Dartmouth rep** will either make or break his future at the school. Unfortunately, it's Nate who nabs the position, despite total disinterest in the school. Meanwhile, Jenny gets closer to Serena's younger brother Eric and Rufus asks Lily for a favor.

1. **Upper East Side** teens of **Constance Billiard and St**, I have no idea what it is talking about. I know you might say that this is an off topic question because it is not about the language but I actually  don't want  you to tell facts about tgat place, just tell what it could be.
2. Could you please simplify **Jude's** and the **visiting representatives' arrival** , in simple English.
3. Could you simplify ** brings more than just college applications** .
4. **coveted usher position** with the **Dartmouth rep** ? Could you simplifying them , not defining , just simplifying.

Answer (score 2):

1. Constance Billard School for Girls is an exclusive ([fictional, from gossip girl](http://gossipgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Constance_Billard_School_for_Girls)) private school. It is run by Headmistress Queller in partnership with St. Jude's School for Boys.
2. 1. You have misunderstood here, Jude's is part of the St, of point 1. St stands for saint, the school is named after [Saint Jude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Jude).
   2. visiting representatives' arrival means that there are people who represent other schools, and they will be visiting. They want to make a good impression, and show off about how good their school(s) are.
3. Not really. "brings more than just college applications" means that when the representatives visit, they get more than just applications for the college - it is insinuating that there will be lots of drama.
4. coveted usher position with the Dartmouth rep - the valued position of helping the representatives of Darthmouth find their seats.